How to generate SHA256 hex string from PEM file and implement root certificate public key pinning in Swift for iOS 12?
I have a PEM file of the ISRG Root X1 certificate which I downloaded from https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/
and I'm trying to implement certificate pinning in my iOS app. I'm specifically interested in public key pinning and I'm targeting iOS 12 and above.
I have two main questions:

How can I generate a SHA256 hex string from the PEM file?

Once I have the SHA256 hex string, how can I implement root certificate public key pinning in Swift using URLSession, without relying on any external libraries?


I would greatly appreciate any assistance or resources that could shed light on this matter. Thank you in advance!
-- Edited
According to what I found on StackOverflow and other sources, the SHA-256 hex string I generated using OpenSSL differs from the one I obtained in the code during TLS connections.
Command used:
openssl rsa -pubin -inform PEM -outform DER -in public_key.pem | openssl enc -base64

Question - why it is different is it expected?

What have you tried so far? How to get the certificate of a TLS connections, extract the public key, get the raw data and then hash it. For all those steps I am sure you will find answers here on stackoverflow. In my opinion the easiest way is to implement the certificate public key pinning and first set a dummy hash in code. If cert pinning goes wrong print the real certificate public key hash in log so that you can copy it in XCode log and paste it into your code.

@Robert Edited the question

"In my opinion the easiest way is to implement the certificate public key pinning and first set a dummy hash in code. If cert pinning goes wrong print the real certificate public key hash in log so that you can copy it in XCode log and paste it into your code"
is it recommended?

You get the hash of the public key contained in the certificate. That is the way you implement public key pinning. Not sure what you mean by "is it it recommended?".

I mean how could I validate the hash is correct? or the code I have written is working?
we often follow this approach
1- Get Certificate
2- Generate Key
3- In Swift write code that generate certificate keys and
4- compare both if it matches then return true otherwise false

A hash is not validated, it is compared. Depending on how you have stored the pinned hash (e.g. as hex encoded string or as byte array) you simply have to compare the expected hash with the actually generated. I would strongly recommend investing some more time learning the cryptographic basics like what is a hash.

I usually have a slightly different approach that i will share to see if it helps.

I download the certificate already in CER format

In a terminal i simply run this command:
openssl s_client -connect <URL> -servername <server-name> < /dev/null | openssl x509 -outform DER > <output-file-name>.cer

Since it seems you already have the PEM file, you can run this command:
openssl x509 -inform PEM -outform DER -in <your-file-name>.crt -out <output-file-name>.cer


You have to include the certificate file with extension CER in your project.

Implementation of certificate pinning


Initialise your URLSession with delegate
URLSession(
    configuration: sessionConfiguration,
    delegate: self,
    delegateQueue: nil
)

Then you simply implement this function:
func urlSession(
    _ session: URLSession,
    didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge,
    completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void
) {

    guard
        let serverTrust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust,
        let serverCertificate = SecTrustGetCertificateAtIndex(serverTrust, 0)
    else {
        completionHandler(.cancelAuthenticationChallenge, nil)
        return
    }

    let certificatesURLs = Bundle.main.urls(forResourcesWithExtension: "cer", subdirectory: nil)
    let certificatesData = certificatesURLs?.compactMap { try? Data(contentsOf: $0) }

    // Compare the server's certificate with the pinned ones
    let serverCertificateData = SecCertificateCopyData(serverCertificate) as Data

    if certificatesData?.contains(serverCertificateData) == true {
        // Found a certificate that matches, allow the connection
        let credential = URLCredential(trust: serverTrust)
        completionHandler(.useCredential, credential)
    } else {
        // Didn't found a certificate that matches, cancel the connection
        completionHandler(.cancelAuthenticationChallenge, nil)
    }
}

This will allow you to have multiple certificates installed, it can be usefully when one is about to expire but you already have the newer one available, so when one expires, the other one will still be validated.

For you first point i.e.
How to generate SHA256 hex string from PEM file
Method 1:
Get public key via terminal command-
Step 1: If you have the pem file with you please use the below openSSL command to get the public key.
openssl rsa -in inputPemFile.pem -pubout -out outputPublicKey.pem

Here, please do make sure your PEM file is in correct format which contains the private key.
Step 2: Now, use below command to extract/read the public key from  outputPublicKey.pem file
cat public_key.pem

Method 2:
Direct method
Step 1: Open Qualys SSL Labs
Step 2: Enter your domain hostname from which you want to extract the public key e.g. https://www.google.com/ and press submit button

Step 3: In the next screen you will get your SHA256 public key, see reference image below

===================================================================
For you second point i.e.
Implement root certificate public key pinning?
Now, if you are using url session then use URL session delegate method i.e.
// User defined variables
private let rsa2048Asn1Header:[UInt8] = [
    0x30, 0x82, 0x01, 0x22, 0x30, 0x0d, 0x06, 0x09, 0x2a, 0x86, 0x48, 0x86,
    0xf7, 0x0d, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x05, 0x00, 0x03, 0x82, 0x01, 0x0f, 0x00
]

private let yourPublicKey: "Your Public Key"

// MARK: URL session delegate:
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
    // your code logic
}

Find below the logic which I basically used:
    //MARK:- SSL Pinning with URL Session
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
    
    var res = SecTrustResultType.invalid
    guard
        challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust,
        let serverTrust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust,
        SecTrustEvaluate(serverTrust, &res) == errSecSuccess,
        let serverCert = SecTrustGetCertificateAtIndex(serverTrust, 0) else {
        completionHandler(.cancelAuthenticationChallenge, nil)
        return
    }
    
    if #available(iOS 12.0, *) {
        if let serverPublicKey = SecCertificateCopyKey(serverCert), let serverPublicKeyData = SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation(serverPublicKey, nil) {
            
            let data: Data = serverPublicKeyData as Data
            let serverHashKey = sha256(data: data)
            print(serverHashKey, serverHashKey.toSHA256())
            //comparing server and local hash keys
            if serverHashKey.toSHA256() == yourPublicKey {
                print("Public Key pinning is successfull")
                completionHandler(.useCredential, URLCredential(trust: serverTrust))
            } else {
                print("Public Key pinning is failed")
                completionHandler(.cancelAuthenticationChallenge, nil)
            }
        }
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
        if let serverPublicKey = SecCertificateCopyPublicKey(serverCert), let serverPublicKeyData = SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation(serverPublicKey, nil) {
            
            let data: Data = serverPublicKeyData as Data
            let serverHashKey = sha256(data: data)
            print(serverHashKey, serverHashKey.toSHA256())
            //comparing server and local hash keys
            if serverHashKey.toSHA256() == yourPublicKey {
                print("Public Key pinning is successfull")
                completionHandler(.useCredential, URLCredential(trust: serverTrust))
            } else {
                print("Public Key pinning is failed.")
                completionHandler(.cancelAuthenticationChallenge, nil)
            }
        }
    }
}

Helper function to convert server certificate to SHA256
private func sha256(data : Data) -> String {
    var keyWithHeader = Data(rsa2048Asn1Header)
    keyWithHeader.append(data)
    var hash = [UInt8](repeating: 0,  count: Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH))
    
    keyWithHeader.withUnsafeBytes {
        _ = CC_SHA256($0.baseAddress, CC_LONG(keyWithHeader.count), &hash)
    }
    return Data(hash).base64EncodedString()
}

If you are using Alamofire, then pass the domain path in the evaluators data in your alamofire session like below
    let evaluators: [String: ServerTrustEvaluating] = [
    "your.domain.com": PublicKeysTrustEvaluator(
        performDefaultValidation: false,
        validateHost: false
    )
]
let serverTrustManager = ServerTrustManager(evaluators: evaluators)
let session = Session(serverTrustManager: serverTrustManager)

Now use this session while calling your alamofire network request.
Hope, I will be able to help you here.
Thanks and regards.
